# StackOverFlowError BufferedWriter issue

Tags: java, json, bufferedwriter, stack-overflow

I'm programming a conversion tool that should take a json file as an input. Due to the problem that json input files may be very large I'll perform a split at the beginning. I have to resort the structure of the input file and because I don't want to keep the whole large file in my memory all the time, I'll split it.
I'm proofing the occurences of a json block by counting the `{` and `}`. If the counter is 0, a split should be performed. That's where the problem is: if the file is about 40MBs large the JVM throws a `StackOverFlowError` and I don't know why.

Here's what I do to perform a split:

```
/*
 * Utility-function to read a json file part by part and save the parts to a separate json file.
 * @param   scanner     The scanner which contains the file and which returns the lines from the file.
 * @param   j               The counter of the file. As the file should change whenever the counter changes.
 * @return  jsonString  The content of the jsonString.
 */
public String readPartOfFileAndSave(String filepath, Scanner scanner, int j) {

    String jsonString = "";
    int i = 0;
    ++j;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String token = scanner.next();

        jsonString += token + System.lineSeparator();
        if (token.contains("{")) {
            i++;
        }
        if (token.contains("}")) {
            i--;
        }
        if (i == 0) {
//                DEBUG
//                if (j % 1000 == 0) {
//                    System.gc();
//                    System.out.println("Garbage Collector called manually");
//                }
            saveFile(filepath, "actor", j, jsonString);
            readPartOfFileAndSave(filepath, scanner, j);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

/*
 * @param   filename    The name of the target file where the content is saved to.
 * @param   j           The counter of the file. As the file should change whenever the counter changes.
 * @param   content     The content of the file.
 */
public void saveFile(String filepath, String fileprefix, int j, String content) {
    File file = null;
    if (this.osValidator.isWindows()) {
        file = new File(filepath + "\\" + fileprefix + "" + j + ".json");
    } else {
        file = new File(filepath + "/" + fileprefix + "" + j + ".json");
    }

    try {
        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile()), "UTF-8"));
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The exception looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:363)
    at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:969)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:717)
    at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.run(GetPropertyAction.java:84)
    at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.run(GetPropertyAction.java:49)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:109)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:88)
    at utility.ReadFileAndSave.saveFile(ReadFileAndSave.java:183)
    at utility.ReadFileAndSave.readPartOfFileAndSave(ReadFileAndSave.java:158)
    at utility.ReadFileAndSave.readPartOfFileAndSave(ReadFileAndSave.java:159)
```

`splitFile()` is called in a separate class. But nothing else happens there.

```
public void splitFile() {
    try {
        ReadFileAndSave reader = new ReadFileAndSave();
        String jsonFilePath = this.converterView.sourceTextField.getText();
        File jsonFile = new File(jsonFilePath);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(jsonFile), "UTF-8");
        int j = 0;
        File newDir = null;
        if (this.osValidator.isWindows()) {
            newDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\temp\\");
        } else {
            newDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/temp/");
        }

        if (!newDir.exists()) {
            newDir.mkdir();
        }

        if (this.osValidator.isWindows()) {
            reader.readPartOfFileAndSave(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\temp\\", scanner, j);
        } else {
            reader.readPartOfFileAndSave(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/temp/", scanner, j);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FilterController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The input file has about 38.000 blocks in it. About 5.200 will be splitted to separate files. Then the exception is thrown.
The JVM seems to have a problem with the BufferedWriter. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What's your recursion stop condition? I don't see one, and so it looks like you'll always keep recursing.

Comment: Additionally, have you checked how deeply you're recursing?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: The recursion returns `""` if the scanner is at EOF.

Comment: I guess you stop when the Scanner is out of tokens, but that may cause you to recurse too deep. Why not go for a stack and a non-recursive solution?

Comment: The file is probably too large to handle this many individual part readers. I'd recommend not using recursion if you're expecting inputs this large.

Comment: @Compass: Mhm. I have to test it without recoursion then. This software should handle files of more than 100MBs size and shouldn't fail at 40MBs already.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Would you mind to post this as a real answer, so I can accept it? The recursion itself was indeed the problem.